# XML to CSV only returning first record

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am converting an XML file of records to CSV. It worked fine when I had just `resource_type` and `names`, but when I added `abstract` and `publisher`, the script only wrote the first record to CSV. I don't understand why or how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import csv

csv_file = open('names.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')

tree = ElementTree.parse('etds.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

records = root.findall('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}mods')
for f in records:
    row = []
    committee = []

    resource_type = f.find('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}typeOfResource').text
    row.append(resource_type)
    abstract = f.find('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}abstract').text
    row.append(abstract)
    publisher = f.find('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}originInfo/{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}publisher').text
    row.append(publisher)

    names = f.findall('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}name')
    for n in names:
        name_text = n.find('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}namePart').text
        role = n.find('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}role/{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}roleTerm').text
        if role == "Committee member":
            committee.append(name_text)
            committee_string = '||'.join(committee)
    row.append(committee_string)

    csv_writer.writerow(row)

csv_file.close()
```

Here are 2 records from etds.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection>
    <mods xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:etd="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:str="http://www.metaphoricalweb.org/xmlns/string-utilities" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-4.xsd" version="3.4">
        <titleInfo>
            <title>Design and modeling of a cable-driven system for delivering balance perturbations</title>
        </titleInfo>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 1</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">aut</roleTerm>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Author</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 2</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">ths</roleTerm>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Thesis advisor</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 3</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Committee member</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 4</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Committee member</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="corporate" authority="naf">
            <namePart>University of Alabama. Department of Mechanical Engineering</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Department</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <typeOfResource>text</typeOfResource>
        <genre authority="local">Electronic Thesis or Dissertation</genre>
        <genre authority="marcgt">thesis</genre>
        <originInfo>
            <place>
                <placeTerm type="code" authority="marccountry">alu</placeTerm>
                <placeTerm type="text">Tuscaloosa, Ala.</placeTerm>
            </place>
            <publisher>University of Alabama Libraries</publisher>
            <dateIssued encoding="w3cdtf" keyDate="yes">2021-07</dateIssued>
        </originInfo>
        <language>
            <languageTerm type="code" authority="iso639-2b">eng</languageTerm>
            <languageTerm type="text">English</languageTerm>
        </language>
        <physicalDescription>
            <form authority="marcform">electronic</form>
            <internetMediaType>application/pdf</internetMediaType>
            <digitalOrigin>born digital</digitalOrigin>
            <extent>51 p.</extent>
        </physicalDescription>
        <abstract lang="eng">This thesis explores the design and modeling of a cable-driven system able to provide balance perturbations for rehabilitation purposes. These balance perturbations can be used for both rehabilitation and prevention of falls. Many current rehabilitation strategies focus on exoskeletal designs with rigid links. These systems are costly, can inhibit subjects' movements, and can induce subjects to make less effort by not challenging balance enough in an effective way. Cable-driven rehabilitation is an alternative solution that can be more cost-effective as well as addressing some of the issues inherent in previous systems.The cable-driven system developed in this thesis provides balance perturbations with a stepping force in one direction via a DC motor that is connected through a cable and a load cell to a harness worn by the subject. Before testing on human subjects, the motor was tested by attaching the system to a heavy object to measure the force of the stall torque during various duty cycles. Through this testing, the motor was found to provide perturbations of up to a maximum of approximately 100 N within 130 milliseconds. Once the force of the stall torque was determined, the system was tested on eight healthy adults with the harness secured to the participants waist and the cable pulling for 0.5 seconds in the posterior direction parallel to the floor. When tested on human subjects, the average measured force was up to approximately 17% lower than the desired force, but the control panel can be recalibrated according to the force measured for improved accuracy in the future. Overall, the system was shown to be a successful method for providing waist-pull force perturbations to human subjects.</abstract>
        <subject authority="proqst">
            <topic>Mechanical engineering</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Cable-driven system</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Rehabilitation</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Robotics</topic>
        </subject>
        <relatedItem type="host" displayLabel="Online Repository">
            <titleInfo>
                <nonSort>The </nonSort>
                <title>University of Alabama Libraries Digital Collections</title>
            </titleInfo>
        </relatedItem>
        <relatedItem type="host" displayLabel="Digital Collection">
            <titleInfo>
                <nonSort>The </nonSort>
                <title>University of Alabama Electronic Theses and Dissertations</title>
            </titleInfo>
            <identifier type="local">u0015_0000001</identifier>
            <identifier type="uri">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/18289</identifier>
            <location>
                <url access="object in context">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/18289</url>
            </location>
        </relatedItem>
        <identifier type="local">u0015_0000001_0003866</identifier>
        <identifier type="proqst">Sung_alatus_0004M_14528</identifier>
        <identifier type="uri">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/181427</identifier>
        <location>
            <url access="object in context" usage="primary">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/181427</url>
        </location>
        <accessCondition type="useAndReproduction" displayLabel="Copyright">All rights reserved by the author unless otherwise indicated.</accessCondition>
        <extension>
            <etd:degree>
                <etd:name>M.S.</etd:name>
                <etd:level>master's</etd:level>
            </etd:degree>
            <etd:discipline>Mechanical Engineering</etd:discipline>
        </extension>
        <recordInfo>
            <recordContentSource authority="oclcorg">ALM</recordContentSource>
            <recordCreationDate encoding="w3cdtf">2021-09-13</recordCreationDate>
            <recordOrigin>Record has been transformed into MODS from a ProQuest/UMI XML record using locally created stylesheet "ProQuest2MODS.xsl".</recordOrigin>
            <languageOfCataloging>
                <languageTerm type="code" authority="iso639-2b">eng</languageTerm>
                <languageTerm type="text">English</languageTerm>
            </languageOfCataloging>
        </recordInfo>
    </mods>
    <mods xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:etd="http://www.ndltd.org/standards/metadata/etdms/1.0/" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:str="http://www.metaphoricalweb.org/xmlns/string-utilities" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-4.xsd" version="3.4">
        <titleInfo>
            <title>Pattern-based discrimination of carboxylate anions in aqueous media and on solid supports</title>
        </titleInfo>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 2-1</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">aut</roleTerm>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Author</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 2-2</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="code">ths</roleTerm>
                <roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Thesis advisor</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 2-3</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Committee member</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 2-4</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Committee member</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 2-5</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Committee member</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="personal" authority="local">
            <namePart>Name 2-6</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Committee member</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <name type="corporate" authority="local">
            <namePart>University of Alabama. Department of Chemistry and Biochemistry</namePart>
            <role>
                <roleTerm authority="local" type="text">Department</roleTerm>
            </role>
        </name>
        <typeOfResource>text</typeOfResource>
        <genre authority="local">Electronic Thesis or Dissertation</genre>
        <genre authority="marcgt">thesis</genre>
        <originInfo>
            <place>
                <placeTerm type="code" authority="marccountry">alu</placeTerm>
                <placeTerm type="text">Tuscaloosa, Ala.</placeTerm>
            </place>
            <publisher>University of Alabama Libraries</publisher>
            <dateIssued encoding="w3cdtf" keyDate="yes">2021-07</dateIssued>
        </originInfo>
        <language>
            <languageTerm type="code" authority="iso639-2b">eng</languageTerm>
            <languageTerm type="text">English</languageTerm>
        </language>
        <physicalDescription>
            <form authority="marcform">electronic</form>
            <internetMediaType>application/pdf</internetMediaType>
            <digitalOrigin>born digital</digitalOrigin>
            <extent>212 p.</extent>
        </physicalDescription>
        <abstract lang="eng">Carboxylate-containing species play important roles in biosynthesis, energy generation and biological signaling; they are also common functional groups in pharmaceuticals, and potential pollutants in aqueous media. Sensing and discrimination of carboxylates was achieved using non-covalent interactions mediated by poly(amidoamine) (PAMAM) dendrimers, a family of macromolecular polyelectrolytes.Our focus was on fast, sensitive, and inexpensive detection methods based on optical spectroscopy. However, neither the dendrimers nor the analytes have spectroscopic signals in the visible region, so we first designed and tested an indicator displacement assay (IDA), built from PAMAM dendrimers and common organic dyes, whose response was monitored through absorbance, fluorescence emission and fluorescence anisotropy (Chapter 2). We achieved qualitative and quantitative discrimination among structurally similar carboxylates using pattern-based clustering methods applied to the output of the IDA sensing system (Chapter 3). It is noteworthy that we obtained not only qualitative discrimination (where pattern recognition commonly excels) but also quantitative measurements, a much rarer accomplishment. In Chapter 4, the scope was extended to the discrimination of β-lactam antibiotics, a family of environmentally and biologically relevant analytes that contain carboxylate groups and comprise more than half of the world market for antibiotics. A novel partial hydrolysis method, introduced here, significantly increased the affinity of these compounds for the PAMAM hosts; this in turn allowed us to successfully differentiate samples drawn from an analyte panel comprising two penicillins, five cephalosporins, and two references. In Chapter 5 we move these carboxylate sensing methods to solid supports with lower cost and higher stability, on a path towards the construction of a portable, deployable device. Studied support media included cellulose acetate, SiO2 dispersions, regular printing paper, filter paper, and chromatography paper. Chromatography paper, the best performer, yielded excellent differentiation and repeatability, and improved long-term stability over the same system in water. Finally, Chapter 6 describes our efforts to improve the determination of the concentration of chloroform, a halogenated byproduct of water chlorination and a dangerous water pollutant. We attempted to improve upon the common colorimetric Fujiwara test, using the intensely colored Fujiwara product as an optical filter to modulate the fluorescence emission of organic fluorophores.</abstract>
        <subject authority="proqst">
            <topic>Analytical chemistry</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject authority="proqst">
            <topic>Chemistry</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Beta-lactam antibiotics</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Carboxylates</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Dendrimer</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Fluorescence</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Paper-based solid supports</topic>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <topic>Pattern-based recognition</topic>
        </subject>
        <relatedItem type="host" displayLabel="Online Repository">
            <titleInfo>
                <nonSort>The </nonSort>
                <title>University of Alabama Libraries Digital Collections</title>
            </titleInfo>
        </relatedItem>
        <relatedItem type="host" displayLabel="Digital Collection">
            <titleInfo>
                <nonSort>The </nonSort>
                <title>University of Alabama Electronic Theses and Dissertations</title>
            </titleInfo>
            <identifier type="local">u0015_0000001</identifier>
            <identifier type="uri">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/18289</identifier>
            <location>
                <url access="object in context">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/18289</url>
            </location>
        </relatedItem>
        <identifier type="local">u0015_0000001_0003867</identifier>
        <identifier type="proqst">Xu_alatus_0004D_14572</identifier>
        <identifier type="uri">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/181428</identifier>
        <location>
            <url access="object in context" usage="primary">http://purl.lib.ua.edu/181428</url>
        </location>
        <accessCondition type="useAndReproduction" displayLabel="Copyright">All rights reserved by the author unless otherwise indicated.</accessCondition>
        <extension>
            <etd:degree>
                <etd:name>Ph.D.</etd:name>
                <etd:level>doctoral</etd:level>
            </etd:degree>
            <etd:discipline>Chemistry</etd:discipline>
        </extension>
        <recordInfo>
            <recordContentSource authority="oclcorg">ALM</recordContentSource>
            <recordCreationDate encoding="w3cdtf">2021-09-13</recordCreationDate>
            <recordOrigin>Record has been transformed into MODS from a ProQuest/UMI XML record using locally created stylesheet "ProQuest2MODS.xsl".</recordOrigin>
            <languageOfCataloging>
                <languageTerm type="code" authority="iso639-2b">eng</languageTerm>
                <languageTerm type="text">English</languageTerm>
            </languageOfCataloging>
        </recordInfo>
    </mods>
</collection>
```

Comment: code looks okay! to look into it further would need your input file `etds.xml`. I don't think adding new fields(abstract and publisher) really created the problem here.

Comment: upload `'etds.xml'` or a subset of it and share the required csv as well

Comment: It's one of the ```abstract``` elements that's causing the problem. The output looks ok when I run it on just the first 2 records I included above.